# Shared DB or Dedicated DB?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

In a production environment, is it better to have dedicated RDS instances for Artifactory and Xray? Or is it okay to have a single RDS instance for both Artifactory and Xray?

It seems like Xray uses a lot of resources during the initial DB sync, indexing of artifacts, and when generating reports. I'm not sure how big of a performance impact this has on Artifactory, so would love to hear from other user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this depends on your organization’s needs. It is essential to consider that there is continuous communication between Artifactory and the database which, in most cases, will result in high database utilization. Hence, it is recommended to have dedicated database instances for Artifactory and Xray applications. We can also avoid a single point of failure for both the applications(in case the database instance has some issues)

If there is a requirement to use only a shared database instance, please make sure that it can handle heavy load and tune it accordingly for both applications.